# People are downvoting over jealousy!

Tags: discussion, voting, abuse

There are some very immature people on this site that will downvote me if I don't choose their answer. Has anyone else had this problem?

Comment: You can show a proof for this?

Comment: I'm jealous you asked this question. -1

Comment: it is not super common but has happened a few times in the last couple weeks, there is no way to prove it as mentioned but sometimes you can just know, On 1 ocassion a guy got really upset that I didnt use his answer and I chose another 1 which was a much better answer, the guy then followed me around and posted negative things on all my post for that day and downvoted me of everything, I am sure the downvotes were from him as they happed right after all his negative talk and after he would post things in a question, then I would get the downvote.

Comment: What does "this site" refer to? To Stack Overflow? To the [***original*** Meta Stack Overflow](https://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/07/meta-is-murder.html)? To this über meta site (whatever its name)? This meta site, in its ***current*** form and name, didn't exist in 2009.

Answer (score 10):

This is something you can't actually prove, so it's just an assumption.

<sub>P.S. If you don't accept this answer, I'll down vote you.</sub>

Comment: @OP: If you *do* accept this answer, I'll downvote you.  Your move, Ian.

Comment: If anybody moves...I'm flagging you all!

Comment: Oooh...a flagging...a flagging...Oooh...flag me too!

Comment: That's it: I'm sending an email to team@stackoverflow.com!

Comment: ***waits for the required moderator intervention***

Comment: Ban them all, Diago!

Comment: It's a logical fallacy to think that not having proof = assumption

Comment: @Lance, not at all... but that seems to be the word of the month on MSO so it's w/e

Comment: The verb to assume is spellt *ass-u-me*

Comment: Wait, was that flagging or flogging?

Answer (score 7):

If it becomes blatant, there are reputation recalculation algorithms that are run on an undisclosed and perhaps not consistent schedule that will adjust for it. I they are being clearly abusive, flag the abusive comment/answer and explain the situation in the flag text box and a moderator will look at it.

Comment: They run periodically? I would say every now and then...

Comment: @John: There is no rule on what the length of the period is although I would say it was aperiodically as the length of that period does change.

Comment: so much for building my bot to downvote my enemies/haters!

Comment: I think they run every 6 to 8 weeks.

Answer (score 6):

If you sincerely have a problem, send an e-mail to team@stackoverflow.com. However before doing that flag the questions/answers you believe this has happened on and why. The moderators will then investigate if necessary.

However the voting mechanism does get checked by regular scripts that will undo common down-voting scenarios.

Answer (score 4):

> People are down-voting over inane reasons!
>
> News at eleven.

People downvote for a number of reasons, not necessarily logical. They also upvote for the same not  necessarily logical reasons.

I think that in the end it evens out.

Also there is no way to know intent of a vote, not until `SO Neural Iterface 0.3.2` goes public Beta in about 6 to 8 weeks.

Comment: Flag post as footstep noise.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think a single occurrence of this is very provable or worthy of being searched for and reversed. However, if there are users who are consistently doing this, I would hope the fraud prevention algorithm does or will look for this and reverse it. It is not a behavior that seems in keeping with the spirit of SO.

Answer (score 2):

While there are those who may partake in this behavior, I believe they are in the minority and a single downvote does not carry enough weight to really have a detrimental impact on your reputation. In addition, if they go on a campaign of retributal downvoting, they will get caught out by the system detecting their unsportsmanlike conduct.